# Twitter Login working fine, but keeps throwing error asking for API key

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have managed to implement twitter login in my Android application. Everything works fine so I'm just trying to keep it clean.

For now I only need to use the Login with Twitter feature, so I followed the instructions indicated here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twittercore

As I said, everything is working fine, but everytime my application starts I get the following error:

```
E/Fabric  ( 8859): Error dealing with settings
E/Fabric  ( 8859): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:93)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:44)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.initialize(Settings.java:68)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:80)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:26)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:46)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:11)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:294)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/Fabric  ( 8859):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I tried adding that value in my manifest file, using my application's Consumer Key, and I get the following error instead:

```
3-24 13:34:38.451  10250-10268/... E/Fabric﹕ Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
    org.json.JSONException: No value for app
            at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
            at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsJsonTransform.buildFromJson(DefaultSettingsJsonTransform.java:24)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:66)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:47)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:139)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:80)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:26)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:46)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:11)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:294)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't understand why I get this error if everything is working fine, that value is clearly not necessary for my intended purposes, so I don't know if Twitter is doing anything extra on the background. Besides that, it doesn't mention anywhere in the docs that I need to provide that value in the manifest in order to use Twitter Login.

**Update:** I presented this same issue in the twitter community. The answer is that "Twitter kit is built on top of Fabric, so it needs the API key to talk with fabric settings". In my opinnion this still doesn't answer my question of what is Twitter doing besides the login. But I guess that if it's built on top of Fabric, it can be attributed to some legacy issues where it's trying to do something necessary for the Fabric platform to work which is not necessary for the login. More info here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-login-working-fine-but-keeps-asking-api-key-android/34383/3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to define some settings for Crashlytics, one of them being an `app` property. It also looks like you are using Fabric which Crashlytics is a part of.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I only want to use Twitter login. So, it seems twitter is trying to do something else, and that's the issue I want to fix. Maybe it's not possible to prevent that from happening, but then I would like to know what's exactly going on.

Comment: Or maybe it's possible that everything with the Twitter auth is working fine and your problem lies elsewhere...